# inTheHand Blutooth_Client.DiscoverDevices() reports "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"

Tags: c#, windows, bluetooth, 32feet

I attempted to write the Server code and Client code using inTheHand.Net.Bluetooth to promote communication between android watch and Windows. However, the line "client.DiscoverDevices();" keeps recording the following error. Is it possible for anybody to have a look and give some help? Really appreciate it if anyone can help by any amount.

**The error message is:**

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Occured at the line:

```
Bluetooth client = new BluetoothClient();
for each (var item in client.DiscoverDevices()) {
    ......
}
```

Such a problem will not occur when running PC-PC communication program using 32Feet.net package.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](https://gist.github.com/salarcode/da8ad2b993e67c602db88a62259d0456) for any permission on android.
Do not call "`new BluetoothClient()`" when the application is loading.
when you do this any subsequent call will fail on `BluetoothRadio.GetDefault`
Try to call "`new BlueotoothClient()`" after application was loaded.